# I am getting an error of Invalid postback or callback argument while i used to put the item templete in my gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am trying to make a program using the gridview data so i used selectedindexchange method to fetch the data from grid view as soon as i put a button using item templete its give me an error of invalid postback or callable argument.please help me

[Thiss is the error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGhDR.png)

Here is my HTML code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnview" Text="view" CssClass="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btnview_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And At Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.DataBind();

    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select emp_id,emp_nm,reason,starting_date,ending_date,request_date from leave where emp_id like 'MN%' ", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.close()
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    id = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text);
    d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text);
    tp = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
}
```

Comment: `con.close() ` is missing a semi colon, and ``enter code here`` is not a valid inline comment ... should be /**/

Comment: Wrap the code in `Page_Load` in a `if(!IsPostBack){ ... }` and remove the `Page.DataBind()`.

Comment: thx Mr. Tim, i really apriciate that but nothing is chang. same error

Answer (score -1):

This article should help you out:

[Why do I get "Invalid postback or callback argument" Errors?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitsh/archive/2007/07/31/why-i-get-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-errors.aspx)

Revelant part:

> In ASP.NET 2.0 we have added a feature called event validation. Event validation checks the incoming POST request to ensure that the
>   event causing the Postback / callback is valid and the event which
>   triggered the Postback /callback is expected by the Runtime. If the
>   runtime finds a Postback / callback by an event which is not
>   registered for validation, it throws an exception.  This has been
>   added in ASP.NET 2.0 explicitly to prevent the attack to the
>   application by spoofing a Postback. Event validation can help prevent
>   injection attacks from malicious users who are trying to POST data by
>   an event which does not come up from the controls registered to the
>   page.
>
> You can enable or disable this feature by simply setting up Property EnableEventValidation = true in the web.config or on the page
>   level. By default it is enabled.

Comment: first of all thank you for your reply,

But i have also set EnableEventValidation= false but i got same error.

the grid view has problem with the button which i place.

Comment: Try setting `<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>` in your web.config.